# Is it possible to run Snow Leopard (Server) inside VirtualBox on a Mac running Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-server, virtualbox

Is it possible to run Snow Leopard (Server) inside VirtualBox on a Mac running Lion, as a means of continuing to run legacy PowerPC apps (Eudora, Quicken, et.al.) under Rosetta, even on new Macs (Lion only)?

The EULA seems to allow running the OS in a VM on Apple Mac hardware.

ADDED:

If so, what VirtualBox configuration and/or settings should one try?
How big a virtual HD should one use?

(My goal is to run authentic vintage apps, if possible, not work-alikes).

Comment: What a great little idea to get PowerPC apps on Lion.

Answer (score 2):

Yup. You should be able to. Give it a try. :)

Though, I hope apps will be updated to work on Intel, because this isn't the most resource-firendly solution. It probably takes more processing power / RAM / Hard Disk Space to install and run Snow Leopard than to run the app itself.

Yet, I think you can find alternative Intel apps. I really like using Apple's Mail for e-mail, and [this article](http://www.macworld.com/article/59617/2007/08/money_alternatives.html) shows several alternatives to Quicken.

Anyhow, its your choice. Give it a try and see what works better for you.